# Firebase + auth0 integration

Tags: angularjs, firebase, auth0

I get the basic idea behind Firebase + auth0, however the part i'm stuck on and I can't seem to find any information on is this,

auth0 holds information about my users, firebase holds data for my users, both of which seem to have different uid's, how do I make these the same?

Do i need to set something in auth0 to import new users into firebase? so that I can then write a firebase rule to compare the auth.id with the $user_id?

Any comments are useful, thanks

Comment: See https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-06-05-auth0-guest-blog.html and https://auth0.com/docs/server-apis/firebase. The blog post contains a pretty complete walkthrough of converting the auth0 token to a Firebase token and how to use this in the security rules. If these links don't cover your needs, describe what you've done.

Comment: Both of those are exactly what i've done and it works as expected from what I can see, however the issue i'm facing is, my auth0 returns the uid within the token as, forexample - 8796504. My firebase $user_id is something more like -Joo48kTZNnan3MJqxp7

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I think what I may be looking for is the "UPDATE USER PROFILE IDENTITY IN FIREBASE" rule available for auth0 to then create a user in my firebase instance with the correct ID

Comment: That `-Joo48kTZNnan3MJqxp7 ` looks like a Firebase push id, not a Firebase user id (`auth.uid`). Note that the blog post uses a provided auth0 `auth.user_id` to secure the data. Please **edit** your question to provide the minimal, complete information. I cannot see your screen and an interactive Q&A is not a very efficient way to get that information. Typically a sample of your JSON data (text please, no screenshots) and the rules file, but maybe more.